# Swapping variables with a function doesn't affect the call site

Tags: c, swap

A few lessons ago I learned about variables, and got a question in my homework about swapping two numbers - I used a third variable to solve this question.

The solution looked somewhat like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x, y;
    scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

    // swappring the values

    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;

    printf("X is now %d and Y is now %d", x, y);
}
```

Now I'm learning about functions, and I wanted to try and solve the previous question with a helper swap function.

This is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int x, int y) {
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    swap(a, b);

    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
}
```

I don't know why, but the output is still `3 4` even though I changed the value inside the `swap()` function.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This is a common problem for new programmers (and a well-asked question).  Do some research on pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference - it's an important concept to understand fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass address of `x` and `y` as arguments to function. Right now they are local variables, changes are not made to original variables .

Do as follows-

```
void swap(int *x,int *y){
 /*            dereference pointers and  swap    */
 int temp = *x;
 *x = *y;
 *y = temp;
}
```

And call in `main` like this -

```
swap(&x,&y);
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks, but could you please explain the logic behind this action? I mean, in terms of C

Comment: @rolory In function call i.e. `swap(&x, &y);` the reference of the variables is passed(viz their address, where they are stored in memory). And in `void swap(int *x, int *y)` the address is dereferenced to get the value stored at the provided location. Thats it.

Comment: @rolory More to it , changes are made to the value of `x` and `y` which are at their address, so value at that address is changed , and it remains in `main` , Therefore, it work correctly .

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is passing parameter by value. It means that during the function call, copies of parameters are created. So inside the function you are working on copies of actual variables.

Instead you need to pass it as a reference. Please read more about pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int& x,int& y)    //Instead of passing by value just pass by reference
{
    int temp=x;
    x=y;
    t=yemp;
}
int main() {
    int a=3,b=4;
    swap(a,b);
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:
C does not have references. Above code will work in c++ instead. To make in work in C, just use pointers and de-reference it inside the function.

Comment: C does not have references.